# Is there a way we can get cooldown time remaining of multiple commands at once in discord.py?

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I'm making a rpg bot on discord and it has multiple commands each having its own cooldown. I want to make a command for the bot which outputs the time remaining for the cooldown of multiple commands. This feature is available in another discord bot (see attached) and I'm trying to replicate that. Is there any way I can do that?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way. Get the command and use the attribute `get_cooldown_retry_after`

```py
@bot.command()
async def some_command(ctx):
    command = bot.get_command('some command name')
    await ctx.send(f"Cooldown left {command.get_cooldown_retry_after(ctx)}
```

And do it for all your commands

Note: `get_cooldown_retry_after` returns the cooldown left in **seconds**.

[commands.Command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_command#discord.ext.commands.Command)